# Can copy/move constructors be inherited by using-declaration in c++17?

Tags: c++, c++14, c++17, language-lawyer, inherited-constructors

```
struct B {
  B(int) {}
  B(B const&) {}
};

struct D: B {
  using B::B;
};

int main(void) {
  B b(5);
  D d(b); // error
  return 0;
}
```

c++14 explicitly excludes copy/move constructors from inherited constructors in 12.9 [class.inhctor]/p3.

> For each non-template constructor in the candidate set of inherited
>   constructors other than a constructor having no parameters or a
>   copy/move constructor having a single parameter, a constructor is
>   implicitly declared with the same constructor characteristics unless
>   there is a user-declared constructor with the same signature in the
>   complete class where the using-declaration appears or the constructor
>   would be a default, copy, or move constructor for that class.

But I could not find any detailed descriptions in c++17. clang/gcc show that copy/move constructors of base class are not inherited. Can someone provide where it is explained in the standard? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The new wording is in [[over.match.funcs]/8](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.funcs#8):

> A constructor inherited from class type `C` ([class.inhctor.init]) that has a first parameter of type “reference to *cv1* `P`” (including such a constructor instantiated from a template) is excluded from the set of candidate functions when constructing an object of type *cv2* `D` if the argument list has exactly one argument and `C` is reference-related to `P` and `P` is reference-related to `D`. [ *Example*:
>
> ```
> struct A {
>   A();                                  // #1
>   A(A &&);                              // #2
>   template<typename T> A(T &&);         // #3
> };
>
> struct B : A {
>   using A::A;
>   B(const B &);                         // #4
>   B(B &&) = default;                    // #5, implicitly deleted
>
>   struct X { X(X &&) = delete; } x;
> };
>
> extern B b1;
> B b2 = static_cast<B&&>(b1);            // calls #4: #1 is not viable, #2, #3, and #5 are not candidates
> struct C { operator B&&(); };
> B b3 = C();                             // calls #4
> ```
>
> — *end example* ]

In your example, `B`'s inherited copy constructor is excluded from the set of candidates (that constructor has a first parameter of type reference to `const B`, the argument list has exactly one argument - `b`, and `B` and `D` are reference-related).

Answer (score 3):

The passage you quote does not in fact prevent inheritance of copy constructors in C++14. Consider this instead:

```
B(B const&, int = 42) {}
```

This is a copy constructor, but it has two parameters. The passage only excludes a copy constructor with a single parameter. And when you supply both arguments, you can in fact initialize a `D` object with this constructor.

`g++` error messages provide some insight.

```
note:   an inherited constructor is not a candidate for initialization from an expression of the same or derived type
```

Aha! A quick search in the draft standard finds [this](http://eel.is/c++draft/over#match.funcs-8)

> A constructor inherited from class type C ([class.inhctor.init](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.inhctor.init)) that has a first parameter of type “reference to *cv1 P*” (including such a constructor instantiated from a template) is excluded from the set of candidate functions when constructing an object of type *cv2 D* if the argument list has exactly one argument and *C* is reference-related to *P* and *P* is reference-related to D.

Comment: D d(X{}); still doesn't compile.